# Problems with ur3 Simulation

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Im pretty new to ros and im trying to get a simulation of a ur3 to work.
Ive been following the instructions on the [universal_robot Git](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot) but i seem to get multiple error messages.

When i clone the Git to my catkin workspace and run all the rosrun commands as instructed

```
roslaunch ur_description ur3_upload.launch 
roslaunch ur3_moveit_config ur3_moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true
roslaunch ur3_moveit_config moveit_rviz.launch config:=true
```

the messages i get are:

```
Skipping virtual joint 'fixed_base' because its child frame 'base_link' does not match the URDF frame 'world'
```

,

```
[ WARN] [1532077114.269386647]: Waiting for /follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ WARN] [1532077120.271582767]: Waiting for /follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR] [1532077126.272691382]: Action client not connected: /follow_joint_trajectory
```

and in RViz i get

```
Global Status: Warn 
    No tf data. Actual error: Fixed Frame [world] does not exist
```

I could get rid of the first problem by following [this suggestion](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/pull/284/commits/a90697e68141b7e19928cc9aecbd388e5eafa366) but renaming all the "world" links doesn't get me any further in solving my "missing fixed world frame" problem.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298025/problems-with-ur3-simulation/) by [Raffzy](https://answers.ros.org/users/36564/raffzy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-07-20

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-20**:\

> ```
> roslaunch ur_description ur3_upload.launch
> ```

The readme in the repository you link does this:

```
roslaunch ur_gazebo ur3.launch
```

That is different from what you do. I would expect things to work if you run the command above.

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2018-07-20**:
Hi! Can you post the results of `rosrun tf view_frames` followed by an `evince frames.pdf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok... turnes out i had a completely different problem.

I do everything on a Virtual Machine (VMware to be specific) and it seems like gazebo has a big issue with using the 3D accerlation setting in VM->settings->display.

Every time i ran

```
roslaunch ur_gazebo ur3.launch
```

the gezebo window popped up, couldn't see a robot but i didn't really connect the dots. Basically nothing but the gazebo window worked.

Because of that i got some "parameters missing" error message when i ran

```
roslaunch ur3_moveit_config ur3_moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true
```

and using

```
roslaunch ur_description ur3_upload.launch
```

seemed to "fix" that issue.

Well, now ive set up a completely new VM with Accerlation turned off and everything worked smoothly.

---

Originally posted by [Raffzy](https://answers.ros.org/users/36564/raffzy/) with karma: 26 on 2018-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-21**:\

> I do everything on a Virtual Machine

Without being overly dramatic, *please* always include such information in your question text. As you've noticed yourself, there was no way we were going to figure this out without knowing that you were using VMWare.

In the future, mention things like this.